# Best SE site to ask about AA battery details?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, beta-sites

Might be a topic that slips in the cracks.  It sort of fits the "consumer electronics" and "gadgets" site attempts, I'm not sure whether it would be welcome in "electrical engineering" or "engineering" among others: I'd love to ask knowledgeable people if there are rechargeable AA-spec batteries which use lithium chemistry :-)  I wonder if "Battery Technology" is a worthwhile idea for a new site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com).  They have a [batteries tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries) and also a [battery-chemistry](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-chemistry) tag, and there is a question entitled [Battery Details](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85585/battery-details) there, where you might find some tips.

Also, if you look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=battery+technology+is%3Aq) search query on that site, you'll find that there are already questions related to battery technology, so I don't think it would be worth proposing a new site just for that.  There are also questions related to that subject on [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/search?q=battery+technology+is%3Aq) (search query again).